# Can I put the main hard disk of a PC into another PC/Server as a secondary hard drive to back up files?

Tags: hard-drive, data-transfer

I want to back up my files from my old PC. My internet connection is fairly slow so I don't really want to wait to copy all files over through ethernet to my home server. Is it possible to put the hard drive of this PC into another PC as a secondary hard drive? What I mean: I have a secondary PC with 2 hard drive slots. One is filled up, the other is empty making space for a second hard drive. Will this PC recognize the main hard drive from the other PC, even if Windows is installed on that disk? (File structure is NTFS, so it would seem logical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as it fits. (For example majority of laptops simply won't fit a desktop 3.5" disk.)

Using a USB enclosure is also an option, but it may be slower if it's USB 2.0 or doesn't support UASP.

The most convenient approach for a 2.5" disk would be to use an eSATA port, but these aren't very common.

Comment: Ahh. I'm not familiar with hard drive sizes, but it's a desktop so I would assume it's a 3.5" disk? It looks quite small, though, but that may just be perspective as it's not clearly visible.

Comment: If it fits in your palm, it's a 2.5" ("laptop") one.

Comment: Ah, then, juding from [this](https://www.deskdecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/enNG0RR-min-696x392.jpg) image, I would assume it's a desktop harddrive, because it's definitely not _that_ small. Thanks for the help!